# How to know which vnode a table is in when using TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I am use TDengine now. I know that TDengine likes Cassandra that both use virtual node as virtualization. How can I know which vnode a table is in? I tried to use `describe tbname`, but I got no information like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Xmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use "show vgroups" to check how many vnodes you have

```
taos> show vgroups;
    vgId     |   tables    |  status  |   onlines   | v1_dnode | v1_status | compacting  |
==========================================================================================
           3 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           4 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           5 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           6 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           7 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           8 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
           9 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
          10 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
          11 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
          12 |        1000 | ready    |           1 |        1 | master    |           0 |
Query OK, 10 row(s) in set (0.001933s)
```

From the output, you know the vgroup id, then you can use "show tables like tbname" to get which vnode the table is in.

```
taos> show tables like "d8645";
           table_name           |      created_time       | columns |          stable_name           |          uid          |     tid     |    vgId     |
==========================================================================================================================================================
 d8645                          | 2022-04-24 14:43:23.183 |       4 | meters                         |      2814763207660351 |         801 |          10 |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.009541s)
```

From the output, you know that table d8645 is in vgroup 10